# Not able to get signature|system permission on an app installed as a system app

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to develop an application where I have to use a permission "android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY" which is protected by "signature|system" protection level.

To use this permission I have copied my apk to /system/app/ location of android 4.4.2 avd to make my application work as a system app.

But when I run the app i get a SecurityException
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkStats: Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY.

I have properly specified the permission in manifest and even installed my app as a system app which should sufficient to use any api protected by above mentioned permission.

Now the question is why am I getting the security exception when my app is eligible to get that permission.

Permission Details :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below permissions as well to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: how are these permissions related to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say that an app has become a system app by just copying it into system/app folder.The main pre-requisite to make an app as a system app is that the app needs to be signed by the same signing keys with which other system apps on the device have been signed with.For a hardware device,these are the keys which the manufacturer uses while signing the OS on the device.